# "Тетрахлорид натрия" пишется вместе или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно "тетрахлорид натрия". Слитно писалось бы, например, "натрийтетрахлорид" или что-то в этом роде.